# Carbon php date time math

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I know when an account is created in UTC. If the account is cancelled before 2am PST the next day then the account needs to be removed, otherwise it is not removed until later. I'm having trouble coming up with the actual statements to use in Carbon. For example:

```php
$account->getAttribute('created_at');
```

returns

```php
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1597790786 {#3432
     date: 2020-08-18 22:46:26.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
```

Therefore I need to know if now() is >= 2020-08-19 02:00:00.0 PDT/PST.

How should I do that?

Comment: I don't get why you need to know if "now" is >= a given date. In your example I see only a comparison between creation date and cancellation date. I don't see where is "now" in the equation you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your date in the timezone to consider `"tomorrow 2am"` then re-switch in UTC for the comparison:

```
$cancellation = $account->getAttribute('cancelled_at');
$creation = $account->getAttribute('created_at');

if ($cancellation < $creation->tz('PST')->modify('tomorrow 2am')->utc()) {
    // remove
}
```